# Problem in implementation of synchronization between producer and consumer using semaphores

Tags: c, concurrency, semaphore, shared-memory, producer-consumer

Like everyone I was trying to understand linux OS better. I was implementing the producer consumer synchronization problem using semaphores.

i)There will be m producer processes and n consumer processes.

ii) A product is presented with a random number.

iii) The `buffer` is shared between all consumer and producer processes while `in` variable is shared between all producer processes and `out` variable is shared between all consumer processes.

iv)All processes will stop once `CTRL`+`C` is entered in the terminal.

Here are the codes:

1.shared.h

```
//assume all required headers included
#define buffer_size 5
#define empty_id 0
#define full_id 1
#define mutex_id 2
#define no_sem 3

struct sembuf signall = {0 , 1, 0};
struct sembuf wait = {0, -1, 0};

#define W(s) semop(s, &wait, 1);
#define S(s) semop(s, &signall, 1);
int shmid;
int *buffer;

union semun
{
                int val;
                struct semid_ds *buf;
                unsigned short  *array;
                struct seminfo  *__buf;

} setvalarg[3];


int *create_shared_mem_buffer()
{
        int *shmaddr;
        key_t key = ftok("/home/******/**/B", 1);
        shmid = shmget(key, buffer_size, IPC_CREAT|0660);
        shmaddr= (int *)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
        return shmaddr;
}


void clear_buffer()
{
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<buffer_size;i++)
                buffer[i]=0;
}

void releaseSHM(int signum)
{
        int status;
        clear_buffer();
        status = shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);

        status = kill(0, SIGKILL);
        exit(signum);
}


int create_semaphore_set()
{
        key_t key= ftok("/home/******/**/A", 1);

        int semid= semget(key, no_sem, IPC_CREAT|0600);

        setvalarg[0].val=buffer_size;
        semctl(semid, empty_id, SETVAL, setvalarg[0]);

        setvalarg[1].val=0;
        semctl(semid, full_id, SETVAL, setvalarg[1]);

        setvalarg[2].val=1;
        semctl(semid, mutex_id, SETVAL, setvalarg[2]);
        return semid;
}
```

2.producer.c

```
#include "shared.h"

void insert_product(int item, int *in, int *buffer)
{
        *in=(*in+1)%buffer_size;
        buffer[*in]=item;
        printf("Producer produces item %d stored in posn %d  \n",item,*in);
}

int shmid1;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int i, pid, item;
        int *in;
        buffer = create_shared_mem_buffer();
        int semid= create_semaphore_set();

        sighandler_t shandler;

        shandler =  signal(SIGINT, releaseSHM);

        shmid1=  shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int),IPC_CREAT | 0777);
        in=(int *)shmat(shmid1, NULL, 0);
        *in=0;

        int m=5;

        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
                pid=fork();
                if(pid==0)
                {
                        while(1)
                        {
                                item=rand();
                                wait.sem_num=0;
                                W(semid);
                                wait.sem_num=2;
                                W(semid);
                                insert_product(item, in, buffer);
                                signall.sem_num=2;
                                S(semid);
                                signall.sem_num=1;
                                S(semid);
                                sleep(2); //sleep has been introduced to slowdown the output.
                        }
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

3. consumer.c

```
#include "shared.h"

int remove_product(int *out, int *buffer)
{
        int item;
        *out=(*out+1)%buffer_size;
        item=buffer[*out];
        buffer[*out]=0;
        return item;
}

int shmid1;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int i, pid, item;
        int *out;
        buffer = create_shared_mem_buffer();
        int semid= create_semaphore_set();

        sighandler_t shandler;

        shandler =  signal(SIGINT, releaseSHM);
        shmid1=  shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int),IPC_CREAT | 0777);
        out=(int *)shmat(shmid1, NULL, 0);
        *out=-1;

        clear_buffer(buffer);

        int n=2;

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
                pid=fork();
                if(pid==0)
                {
                        while(1)
                        {
                                wait.sem_num=1;
                                W(semid);
                                wait.sem_num=2;
                                W(semid);
                                item=remove_product(out, buffer);
                                printf("Consumer consumes the product %d \n", item);
                                signall.sem_num=2;
                                S(semid);
                                signall.sem_num=0;
                                S(semid);
                                sleep(2); //sleep has been introduced to slow down the output
                        }
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

The output is somewhat like this:

```
Producer produces item 1681692777 stored in posn 2  
Producer produces item 1681692777 stored in posn 3  
Producer produces item 1681692777 stored in posn 4  
Producer produces item 1804289383 stored in posn 1  
Producer produces item 1804289383 stored in posn 2  
Producer produces item 1804289383 stored in posn 3  
Producer produces item 1804289383 stored in posn 0  
Producer produces item 1804289383 stored in posn 0  
Producer produces item 1681692777 stored in posn 0  
Producer produces item 1714636915 stored in posn 1  
Producer produces item 1714636915 stored in posn 2  
Producer produces item 1714636915 stored in posn 3  
Producer produces item 846930886 stored in posn 1  
Producer produces item 1714636915 stored in posn 4  
Producer produces item 846930886 stored in posn 2  
Producer produces item 1714636915 stored in posn 0  
Producer produces item 846930886 stored in posn 3  
Producer produces item 846930886 stored in posn 4  
Producer produces item 846930886 stored in posn 0  
Producer produces item 1681692777 stored in posn 1
```

```
Consumer consumes the product 424238335 
Consumer consumes the product 424238335 
Consumer consumes the product 424238335 
Consumer consumes the product 424238335 
Consumer consumes the product 719885386 
Consumer consumes the product 719885386 
Consumer consumes the product 719885386 
Consumer consumes the product 719885386 
Consumer consumes the product 719885386 
Consumer consumes the product 1649760492 
Consumer consumes the product 1649760492 
Consumer consumes the product 596516649 
Consumer consumes the product 1649760492 
Consumer consumes the product 1649760492 
Consumer consumes the product 1649760492 
Consumer consumes the product 596516649 
Consumer consumes the product 596516649 
Consumer consumes the product 596516649
```

As you can see, the same product is produced more than once and same product is consumed more than once.

i)What is the problem? How to resolve it?

ii) Also the processes donot stop when `CTRL`+`C` is entered.

I have done it all by myself and I need someone to review it. If further information needed, drop a comment below.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to understand your intended purpose for the apparently three semaphores that you're using in your logic.  However, the problem is that you're "racing" for pulling off the numbers.  And your logic is too complex.

Basically, you need this:

1. A **semaphore** which counts the number of numbers that are waiting to be consumed.  `post()` the semaphore when you add a number; `wait()` to get one.
2. A **mutex** which controls access to the list itself, so that only one thread at a time can actually be inserting or removing values from the segment.

You might also need another semaphore which limits the number of entries that *can be* added to the segment ... you `wait()` for permission to add the entry, and as the other processes remove the entry (thus freeing up a slot) they `post()` to let anyone who's waiting proceed.

Finally:  what you're doing here is an *exercise.*  In real life there are "pipes" and other IPC mechanisms available "off the shelf" which will take care of these details for you.

Comment: full semaphore is to stop consumer processes to access buffer if full is 0, empty semaphore is to stop producer processes to access buffer if empty is 0. Mutex semaphore is for mutual exclusion. Yes I know that `wait()` and `post()` would have been simpler but I wanted to study the actual structure of semaphore and implement that.

Comment: Pipe mechanism is for related processes(parent & child). For independent processes we need shared memory and when there is shared memory, there are concurrency issues and semaphore is used for that internally. This is what I have understood so far.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you `fork()` into several (five for m=5) processes:

```
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
            pid=fork();
```

and here, you are producing random item numbers:

```
            item=rand();
```

but all processes are using the same seed (which is `1`, because you did not call `srand()` before)! So, all forked processes generate the *same sequence of random numbers*. This is the reason why you add every item 5 times. Try seeding the rng with a different number for each processes, for example by adding an `srand()` here:

```
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
            srand(m);
            pid=fork();
```

Then, no duplicates should be added.

Comment: It didn't help. As you mentioned, I wrote `srand(time(0))` before `fork()` and the result is the same; product enters into all positions in the buffer. Moreover in the consumer process I get some output as `Consumer consumed the product 0` which means the product is not produced but consumed!!! you can just confirm.

Comment: @Hamsa Please read carefully, I said `srand(m)`. `srand(time(0))` does not work, because all processes are spawned _in the same second_. You could also do `srand(time(NULL)+m)` or `srand(getpid())` inside the `if (pid == 0)` block.

Comment: `srand(m)` before `pid=fork()` doesnot work for me. But `srand(getpid())` inside `if (pid==0)` works. Would you mind addressing my second problem? The processes don't stop when pressed `CTRL`+`C`.